# zk SNARKs based anonymous voting

Tags: cryptography, zero-knowlage

I want to implement zk-SNARKs based anonymous voting. Are there examples or packages available for substrate? Where can I get started.

Comment: There are plenty of zk-SNARK libraries written in rust. Not sure if they are usable under no_std environment. As long as it works, it should be pretty straightforward to use that inside a pallet. In the early days there's a project called ZeroChain developed by the LayerX team, but its development was halt for some time. It's still a good code reference though.

Answer (score 2):

I know that https://manta.network uses ZK for their solution, so you could see how they have gone about things: https://github.com/Manta-Network/manta-signer. They did a [sub0 talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ayelscjnx2E).

I am a beginner in this space, but [plonky2](https://github.com/mir-protocol/plonky2) might be fast enough in wasm if it switches to using portable simd (and that allows wasm simd to happen).

For ZK specific stuff, https://crypto.stackexchange.com/ is also a good place to ask questions.